How to make subdirectories work in out-of-tree Linux Kernel Driver with Kbuild?
I have repository with out-of-tree kernel driver that builds and works. In a subdirectory I have a device tree overlay that I can build and use, but I wanted the .dtbo to be built with the driver code, mostly to handle that in DKMS.
Kbuild:
obj-m := mydriver.o
mydriver-objs += mydriver-dev.o mydriver-controls.o mydriver-registers.o
mydriver-objs += mydriver-status-sysfs.o mydriver-sysfs.o

subdir-y := device-trees

Makefile:
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
# legacy compatible kbuild part of makefile
  include Kbuild
else
# local normal makefile for external module

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
BUILDDIR ?= $(shell pwd)/build
SRCDIR ?= $(shell pwd)

all default: modules
install: modules_install

modules modules_install help clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(BUILDDIR) src=$(SRCDIR) $@

endif

This works without subdir-y :=  present. If this is uncommented as above, I'm getting recurrence regardless of what's in the device-trees directory. And I followed much advice I found on SO and the official Kbuild instructions.
Symptoms:
make -C /lib/modules/6.6.31-current-bcm2712/build M=/home/builder/projects/platform_v4l2_driver/build src=/home/builder/projects/platform_v4l2_driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.31-current-bcm2712'
scripts/Makefile.build:64: '/home/builder/projects/platform_v4l2_driver/build/device-trees/mydriver.ko' will not be built even though obj-m is specified.
scripts/Makefile.build:65: You cannot use subdir-y/m to visit a module Makefile. Use obj-y/m instead.
scripts/Makefile.build:64: '/home/builder/projects/platform_v4l2_driver/build/device-trees/device-trees/mydriver.ko' will not be built even though obj-m is specified.
scripts/Makefile.build:65: You cannot use subdir-y/m to visit a module Makefile. Use obj-y/m instead.
scripts/Makefile.build:64: '/home/builder/projects/platform_v4l2_driver/build/device-trees/device-trees/device-trees/mydriver.ko' will not be built even though obj-m is specified.
scripts/Makefile.build:65: You cannot use subdir-y/m to visit a module Makefile. Use obj-y/m instead.
scripts/Makefile.build:64: '/home/builder/projects/platform_v4l2_driver/build/device-trees/device-trees/device-trees/device-trees/mydriver.ko' will not be built even though obj-m is specified.
scripts/Makefile.build:65: You cannot use subdir-y/m to visit a module Makefile. Use obj-y/m instead.
...

If I replace subdir-y := with obj-y := device-trees/ (which as I understand I shouldn't use if the subdirectory doesn't have code built to binary) I'm getting even worse recursion.
Does anyone understand this well enough to help and provide a good example how to make this work?
Minimal (non)working example
